# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException , java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependencies, xml-configuration

Can anyone tell me, why this error is happening ?
Actually I can't understand where to start resolve it.

```
Nov 19, 2016 10:20:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accessDeniedController' defined in file [D:\java-git-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\wps\WEB-INF\classes\controller\AccessDeniedController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'wpsManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/wpsContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'passwordManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'passwordManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/userContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.greytip.wps.service.impl.PasswordManagerImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.springframework.security.context.SecurityContext cannot be resolved
    The import org.springframework.security.context.SecurityContextHolder cannot be resolved
    SecurityContext cannot be resolved to a type
    SecurityContextHolder cannot be resolved
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base exception that caused the massive exception cascade all the way up was

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
```

This means hat one of your java files had invalid syntax and a compiler error message, and failed to compile successfully.  YOu should probably rebuild the entire project and check all the source for compile errors.   The class in error is likely

```
com.greytip.wps.service.impl.PasswordManagerImpl
```